# Side menu align

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

I designed a responsive layout in Fireworks, and i'm programming it.

No problem even before passing the resolution 1366 x 768:
[image: at 1366x768]

Now, if I take some of the zoom ('increase' resolution):
[image: Wow! Align problem!]

Not least, the current codes, content HTMLL:

```
<div id="content">
        <div id="content-wrapper">
            <div class="wrapper">
                CONTENT HERE
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content-menu">
            <div class="wrapper">
                MENU HERE
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now, content and menu (reduced) codes:

```
#content-wrapper{
    float: left;
    width: 65.88579%;

}

#content-wrapper .wrapper{
    float: right;
    width: 88.88889%;
    max-width:800px;
}

#content-menu{
    float:right;
    width: 34.11420%;
}

#content-menu .wrapper{
    float: left;
    width: 78.54077%;
    max-width:366px;
    height: auto;
}
```

To header bar, this is wrapper code, note max-width:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 85.35871%;
    max-width: 1166px;
    height:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Zooming is different..it dosent mean increase in resolution..check it on this tool..http://www.browserstack.com/responsive..

Comment: The same problem occurred. :/ The zoom is not the same thing, but simulates perfectly. :)